# Mapper vs Constructor

Tags: c#, automapper

I am working on a project that was setup with AutoMapper.  Since most of this is foreign to me, I am keeping an open mind as to why.

Let's say I have two classes:

```
class Foo
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int rank { get; set; }
    public bool isDelected { get; set; }
}

class FooView
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int rank { get; set; }
}
```

instead of using an ORM, why wouldn't I just use a constructor which takes FooView as a parameter.

```
class Foo
{
    public Foo(FooView source)
    {
        this.name = source.name;
        this.rank = source.rank;
    }
}
```

In this case whenever I have a FooView and I need Foo I just say

```
var myFoo = new Foo(FooView);
```

It give me all the logic I need in one location and I can use it everywhere. If I need to update the code it is same place as the Model definition. So what am I missing?

Comment: You can do this, but what if you have 20, 30 or more properties? Automapper will map these automagically if the names match. That alone is worth any configuration overhead.

Comment: You should read up on the benefits of [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) and then decide for yourself if you want to use it or not. One (*there is much more functionality than just this*) of the benefits of automapper is that it can automatically map values across 2 objects if the properties have the exact same signature (both must also have public setter/getter). This could be the same type (like a clone) or of different types. This could save a lot of code especially if there are many view models that closely resemble the business/data logic models.

Comment: I think like @MattyM pointed out that this a big improvement also test-ability and consistence. One of the first points in the `AutoMapper` documentation explains why to use it :)

Comment: Interesting and agreeable comments. I happen to be in the "prefer to avoid AutoMapper" camp. If other devs on my team wish to employ it, we have one essential requirement. There must be unit tests which test the mapping (directly or indirectly). It's very easy to make bad assumptions with this technology. And we've seen multiple times where a develop modifies code not realizing that the mapping will NOT map the some new/old field after the changes. I'm talking about large enterprise applications with a lot of developers. The added value for me doesn't exceed the risk.

Comment: Coincidentally, the constructor based approach you mention is one recommended pattern we offer instead of AutoMapper. The litmus test for me is the moment we have to write complex mapping code is the moment we might as well just write that same code without AutoMapper. The primary benefits I see with AutoMapper (when done right) is the ability to abstract out the mappings.

Comment: It’s not a question when the situation is as simple as in this example. AutoMapper makes it a lot easier as soon as you no longer have immutable properties and need to map deeper structures recursively. Then you can just set up a mapping for each type and it automatically just works. But I agree that you need to reach that point of complexity first before using AutoMapper becomes preferable over simple copy constructors.

Answer (score 4):

In general, I like the pattern you're following. Even though it makes me somewhat of a heretic, I prefer to manually map everything. For example, database pocos and further transforming database pocos to view models. Yes, you could make the argument about certain classes having an abundance of properties. But maybe that's a code smell?

If your project happens to have a ton of these legitimate classes with 20-30 properties, then perhaps you should take a quick break, teach yourself [PowerShell](https://github.com/powershell/powershell) and start generating the mappings.

So why go through all this effort? It's simple, reflection is expensive and it sucks. It loves resources, and is guaranteed to make your code slow despite whatever efforts you make caching etc when things scale even moderately. It's also more difficult to debug.

I'm just simply not in love with handing over the decision making, of perhaps the most brittle part of my code, over to the runtime.

Now on to the constructor vs mapper debate. For a small project, I would reckon that constructor's will work perfectly. It's easy to understand and test. As the project grows, mapper's become a nice touch because they allow for a [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). But as is always the case, don't immediately reach for a library, think about the problem your faced with and try and solve it with code.

In our case, we're looking to project one thing into another, so let's define a simple interface for that:

```cs
public interface IMapper<in TSource, in TResult>
    where TResult : new() {
        void Map(TSource source, TResult result);
}
```

This describes a generic interface with two input types `TSource` and `TResult`, the latter having a `new()` constraint so we can manufacture it programmatically.

Now let's add some functionality, for mapping one-to-one, one-to-one with nulls and many-to-many:

```cs
public static class IMapperExtensions {
    public static TResult Map<TSource, TResult>(this IMapper<TSource, TResult> mapper, TSource source)
        where TResult : new() {
        TResult result = new TResult();

        mapper.Map(source, result);

        return result;
    }

    public static TResult MapAllowNull<TSource, TResult>(this IMapper<TSource, TResult> mapper, TSource source)
        where TResult : new() {
        if (source == null) {
            return default(TResult);
        }

        return mapper.Map(source);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TResult> MapCollection<TSource, TResult>(this IMapper<TSource, TResult> mapper, IEnumerable<TSource> source)
        where TResult : new() {
        if (source == null) {
            yield return default(TResult);
        }
        else {
            foreach (var s in source) {
                yield return mapper.Map(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

An the implementation:

```cs
class Foo {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int rank { get; set; }
    public bool isDelected { get; set; }
}

class FooView {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int rank { get; set; }
}

class FooToFooView : IMapper<Foo, FooView> {
    public void Map(Foo source, FooView result) {
        result.name = source.name;
        result.rank = source.rank
    }
}
```

> Whatever you do, resist the urge to define a static method for this. Elect either the constructor, or the mapper.

Answer (score 2):

This may be fine if all of your models are in the same assembly or have a direct dependency on the other items.  AutoMapper is great if your models align nicely, but if you need a bit more control over the mapping I tend to put these in a static mapping method in a dedicated helper or within the MVC Controller.

This helps keep my mapping logic separate from the models

```
private static Foo MapToFoo(FooView vm) 
{
    var foo = new Foo();
    foo.Name = vm.Name;
    foo.Rank = vm.Rank;
    ...
    return foo;
}
```